# How can I sync two videos together in Corel VideoStudio Pro X3

Tags: video, sync

I have two videos of a dance at a dance competition taken by two different people. The videos are of the same dance but are from different angles.

I want to create a single video that contains both videos side by side and synchronised to the same point. The videos start and finish a few seconds apart from each other and thus are slightly different length.

My video application is Corel VideoStudio Pro X3. How can I do this? I imagine that somehow using the audio this could be done. The music should act as a good guide for syncing them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically. It has to be done manually by matching the frames together from the two videos. This can be done by placing the videos in separate overlay tracks and works for two or more videos.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Corel VideoStudio Pro X3, here is a tip:

**Did you know ?** 
You can import your projects as videos into your timeline before actually rendering them. So You can do all your touchups and effects (all that doesn't alter the length of the clip) to match the tone and look & feel of the two cameras, then simply save the two clips as VSP (project file). Start a new project and simply add the two VSP's on to two Video tracks and there you are.. Same looking clips available for your sync Editing.
*[ Pardon me if you already knew this. And thanks for bearing with me ]*

Comment: Although not relevant to the original question, this is quite a handy tip. Didn't know about this. Thanks.